# Merge dataframes with unequal rows, and no matching column names R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to take df1 (a summary table), and merge it into df2 (master summary table). 
This is a snapshot of df2, ignore the random 42, just the answer to the ultimate question.
[image: df2]
This is an example of what df1, looks like.

[image: df1]

Lastly, I have a vector called Dates. This matches the dates that are the column names for df2.
I am trying to cycle through 20 file, and gather the summary statistics of that file. I then want to enter that data into df2 to be stored permanently. I only need to enter the Earned column. 
I have tried to use merge but since they do not have shared column names, I am unable to. 
My next attempt was to try this. But it gave an error, because of unequal row numbers.

```
df2[,paste(Dates[i])] <- cbind(df2,df1)
```

Then I thought that maybe if I specified the exact location, it might work.

```
df2[1:length(df1$Earned),Dates[i]] <- df1$Earned
```

But that gave and error "New columns would leave holes after existing columns"
So then I thought of trying that again, but with cbind.

```
df2[1:length(df1$Earned),Dates[i]] <- cbind(df2, df1$Earned)
##This gave an error for differing row numbers
df2 <- cbind(df2[1:length(df1$Earned),Dates[i]],df1$earned)
## This "worked" but it replaced all of df2 with df1$earned, so I basically lost the rest of the master table
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If they have uneven lengths and no common variables, it makes more sense to store them inside a list.

Comment: The issue with a list, is that I am running it through a for loop, and the end product of df2 will be a triangular dataframe. If I were to use a list, how would I keep track of what year and date the value corresponds to.

Comment: You can store dataframes inside the list. If said dataframes have the collums you want, you just need to stack square brackets and use double brackets to unlist elements - for instance list_1["DF_1"][["Collum_1"]] would a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
df1[df1$TreatyYear %in% df2$TreatyYear, Dates] <- df2$Earned
```

**Example**

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA,4,4))
df$X1 <- 1:4

df[df$X1 %in% c(1,2),c("X3","X4")] <- c(1,2)
```

Comment: This still gives an error for unequal row lengths. The issue comes from that `df1$TreatyYear %in% df2$TreatyYear` simply just presents truth values. For subsetting a dataframes row, I would have to present it a number.

Comment: Run `2009:2019 %in% 2009:2010`. How come this gives all TRUEs? There may be an issue in your code.

Comment: You're right. I have switched the values so that it was 2009:2010 %in% 2009:2019. Giving me just 2 Truth values. Once I switched the dataframes around it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I have found so far is to force df1$Earned into a vector. Then append the vector to be the exact length of the df2. Then I am able to insert the values into df2 by the specific column.

```
temp_values <- append(df1$Earned,rep(0,(length(df2$TreatyYear)-length(df1$TreatyYear))),after=length(df1$Earned))
df2[,paste(Dates[i])] <- temp_values
```

This is kind of a roundabout way to fix it, but not a very pleasant way. Any better ideas would be appreciated.